# Remove instances of self mutating objects

Tags: javascript

Having a object that create new instances of itself on user request. My question is regarding how to structure this and mostly how to properly remove instances.

Basically it is something like this:

```
(function (something) {
    var collection = {},
        counter = -1;

    function remove(ix) {
        delete collection[ix];
    }

    function Foo() {
        collection[++counter] = this;
        this.index = counter;
        this.load();
    }
    Foo.prototype.load = function () {
        /* - Create some element and add it to DOM.
         * - Add listeners for events. 
         * - If "New" is clicked call this.add()
         * - If "Remove" is clicked call this.remove()
         * */
    };
    Foo.prototype.add = function () {
        var x = new Foo();
    };
    Foo.prototype.remove = function () {
        /* - Remove listeners.
         * - Remove element from DOM.
         * */
        remove(this.index);
    };

    something.Foo = Foo;
})(this);

var bar = new Foo();
```

Are the *"self created"* instances going to be properly removed with this approach? (As in GB collected sometime in the future.) Is there a better way to solve this?

Can I say:

```
delete collection[ix];
```

from within the `remove()` function? Or, do I have to use `setTimeout()` when calling `remove()`? Or, ... other things?

Comment: If you're removing them from your `collection` AND there are no other references one of those removed objects elsewhere in your code, then the garbage collector will clean them up.  `delete collection[ix];` works fine to remove an item from the `collection` as long as `ix` is the key that you used in the original constructor when you added it to the collection.

Comment: +1 I would like to see a detailed answer on this one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is fine.

Doing `delete collection[ix]` or `collection[ix] = null` both would eliminate the reference to the value of `collection[ix]`.

Of course, using `delete` would be preferable if you're going to enumerate over the properties of `collection`, since the object will now be removed from the list. If you simply set it to `null`, that value will still exist as a property of `collection`:

Setting to `null`:

```
collection["x"] = 1
collection["x"] = null;
console.log(collection)// { x: null }
```

vs `delete`:

```
collection["x"] = 1
delete collection["x"]
console.log(collection)// {}
```

Comment: Great. Suspected as much, but had to get it confirmed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the *"self created"* instances will be eligible for garbage collection as soon as there's no references to them.

When you create a new instance of `Foo` with the code `var bar = new Foo();`, you're creating two references to the instance: one in scope in the function closure (the one assigned to a property of `collection`) and one in global scope (the one assigned to `bar`).

When you call `bar.remove();`, you'll remove the reference stored in `collection`. Unless you create other references to the instance, it'll be eligible for garbage collection as soon as the reference stored in `bar` is removed, for example by assigning something else to it.

Comment: Thanks. Looking at the code I guess I can add a small initiator instead of `Foo` to the *public*. Becomes a question on if there is any need for the main object to be accessible. As it stands now I can't see any and it would be easy to change if needed.